# store foreign key as zero instead of it's value

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a table that all the values are foreign keys ,when I store these values it save it as zero not the value that I chose ,

```php
public function create()
{
    $type=type::query()->pluck('type');
    $color=color::query()->pluck('colore');
    $region=region::query()->pluck('country');
    $size=size::query()->pluck('size');
    $brand=brand::query()->pluck('company');
    //$price=new_product::query()->pluck('price');
    return view('sale',compact('type','color','region','size','brand'));
}

public function store(Request $request)
{

    new_product::create($request->all());
    return redirect()->route('sale.index');
}
```

the model:

```php
class new_product extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'enter_new_product';
    protected $fillable = ['type_id', 'color_id', 'region_id', 'size_id', 'brand_id','price'];

    public function type()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(type::class);
    }

    public function size()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(size::class);
    }

    public function color()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(color::class);
    }

    public function region()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(region::class);
    }

    public function brand()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(brand::class);
    }
}
```

the sale  view

```php
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'sale.store', 'method' => 'post','files'=>true]) !!}

                <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('type_id', 'اسم الصنف') !!}
                    {!!Form::select('type_id',$type ,null, ['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'ادخل اسم الصنف '])!!}
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('color_id', 'اللون') !!}
                    {!!Form::select('color_id', $color,null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'ادخل  اللون '])!!}
                </div>
{!! Form::submit('اضافة',array('class'=>'btn btn-primary btn-lg'))!!}
                {!!Form::close()!!}
```

it's a part of the view not all but the region,size and brand are the same as the color and type>

Comment: Please post the result of `dd($request->all());`.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir 
array:7 [▼ "_token" => "m0ew5LonZDGdvDGBt1Vsrbk6cHXCz2nR7gpueqle" "type_id" => "1" "color_id" => "1" "region_id" => "4" "size_id" => "0" "brand_id" => "0" "price" => "120" ] this is the json result . i added a size and brand but it count them as zero , and if i changed the request with other values the zero mostly the result of any other columns .i don't know why .?

Comment: What's the result of `dd((new new_product($request->all()))->getAttributes());`?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir 
array:6 [▼
  "type_id" => "0"
  "color_id" => "1"
  "region_id" => "6"
  "size_id" => "0"
  "brand_id" => "2"
  "price" => "760"
]

Comment: Which columns are `0`? All of them?

Comment: all of the columns get the value zero but they change every time i change the inputs @JonasStaudenmeir

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice to know how your request is looking (`dd($request->all()`) as a comment mentioned before, however I see one problem already, which probably would not help your main problem: The product has the foreign key so it does not have many of the regions and brands and the other stuff. The product `hasOne` of these relations.

Comment: array:7 [▼
  "_token" => "m0ew5LonZDGdvDGBt1Vsrbk6cHXCz2nR7gpueqle"
  "type_id" => "1"
  "color_id" => "1"
  "region_id" => "4"
  "size_id" => "0"
  "brand_id" => "0"
  "price" => "120"
]
this is the json result . i added a size  and brand but it count them as zero , and if i changed the request with other values the zero mostly the result of any other columns .i don't know why .?

Comment: I would try to convert the types to INT and would not use the `$request->all()` rather try to write out `$product = new Product::create(['type_id' = $request['type_id'], ...]); $product->save();` which is longer, but you can see what happening better. 

Yes, maybe you do not need `save()` but I use it always, just in case. 
And name the model `Product` or `NewProduct`, models are always camel case and mostly one word.

For the zeroes: how does the view looks like? And if posting the view (you can update the question up here) please include the content of the `sale` variable.

Comment: You can always try to create the `NewProduct` and then create the associations like described here [Link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#updating-belongs-to-relationships).

Comment: i did what you asked me to do ,but i got an error ,
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`my_queen`.`enter_new_product`, CONSTRAINT `enter_new_product_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`type_id`) REFERENCES `type` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `enter_new_product` (`type_id`, `color_id`, `region_id`, `brand_id`, `price`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (0, 1, 0, 0, 670, 2018-07-02 21:13:47, 2018-07-02 21:13:47))
i uploaded a part of the view not all ,stack overflow refused too much code

Comment: Which method did you used? How did you get the values? You cannot upload `0` to foreign key because it has to be `NULL` or should be existing value in the other table.

Comment: oh, i solved the problem by adding the id column to pluck method ,thank you ^^ 
@Levente Berky